# Scrollbar Legend TDBchart

Tags: delphi-2007, teechart

I have a project delphi 2007, I use the composant TDBCHART, I add the legend for the TDBCHart, My problem is I want to add a vertical scrollbar to the legend , But a didin't found a solution.

My teechart version is 2011.

Comment: Hello,
Could you confirm us if you use the TeeChart VCL Pro, Standard or Lite?

Comment: hello thanks for your response,  I use the Teechart VCL Pro

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do as you want is using the TeeLegendScroll Bar tool. The code below shows you how can do it:

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, TeeGDIPlus, TeEngine,ExtCtrls,  TeeProcs, Chart;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    DBChart1: TDBChart;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
uses Series, TeeTools,TeeLegendScrollBar;
var series1:TLineSeries;
legendtool :TLegendScrollBar;
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
DBChart1.View3D := False;
series1 := TLineSeries.Create(self);
DBChart1.AddSeries(series1);
series1.FillSampleValues(200);
legendtool := TLegendScrollBar.Create(self);
DBChart1.Tools.Add(legendtool);
end;
```